# Applications of ω-automaton in engineering

Tags: automata, finite-automata, software-engineering, applications

[Finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) is a well-known topic which finds applications in software engineering (e.g. pattern matching or regular expressions in general).

[ω-automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-automaton) are another kind of automaton, defined similarly to finite automaton except that they are designed to be run on infinite words (which can be thought of as *streams*) and have an *acceptance condition* instead of *accepting states*.

**I am looking for usage of ω-automaton in engineering. In particular, do you know some software that rely on some kind of ω-automata?**

Answer (score 4):

Sure.  They are used in model checking.  Specifically, if we want to check [liveness properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_and_liveness_properties) of systems, then typically we use $\omega$-automata (e.g., Büchi automata) to formalize the property we are trying to verify, and to model the composition of property + system under verification.  For example, a [standard way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic_to_B%C3%BCchi_automaton) to do model checking of LTL formulas is to convert LTL to a Büchi automaton, then work with these automata.  A classic paper is [An Automata-Theoretic Approach to Automatic Program Verification](https://orbi.uliege.be/bitstream/2268/116609/1/lics86.pdf) by Vardi and Wolper.

I believe one good example of a software tool is [SPIN](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Edthain/courses/cse66771/summer2014/papers/spin.pdf), a very widely used model checker that takes this approach.

If you want to look for more examples, you could check Google Scholar to look for tool papers that [cite the Vardi-Wolper paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=15282580403149822333&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en).  Also, I *think* TLA+ might use $\omega$-automata for checking liveness but I'm not sure.

Comment: Would you have an example of a software implementing ω-automaton for such usage? (even better, if the code is open source)

Comment: @Weier, see revised answer.